# Loopback MongoDB GeoIp 'near' query from angular client

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, loopbackjs

I am working with a loopback angular project, mongoDB as database. Searching for nearest user by latitude and longitude in loopback mongoDB query,  using 'near' keyword causing error.

Note: I indexed 'loc' field in 2d.

Error:

```
> D:\nodejs\your-time\version_1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\nodejs\your-time\version_1\node_modules\express
\lib\response.js:719:10)
    at HttpContext.done (D:\nodejs\your-time\version_1\node_modules\strong-remot
ing\lib\http-context.js:651:9)
    at D:\nodejs\your-time\version_1\node_modules\strong-remoting\lib\rest-adapt
er.js:492:11
    at D:\nodejs\your-time\version_1\node_modules\strong-remoting\node_modules\a
sync\lib\async.js:251:17
    at D:\nodejs\your-time\version_1\node_modules\strong-remoting\node_modules\a
sync\lib\async.js:154:25
    at D:\nodejs\your-time\version_1\node_modules\strong-remoting\node_modules\a
sync\lib\async.js:248:21
    at D:\nodejs\your-time\version_1\node_modules\strong-remoting\node_modules\a
sync\lib\async.js:612:34
    at interceptInvocationErrors (D:\nodejs\your-time\version_1\node_modules\str
ong-remoting\lib\remote-objects.js:690:22)
    at D:\nodejs\your-time\version_1\node_modules\loopback-phase\node_modules\as
ync\lib\async.js:154:25
```

And my Code is below:

```
Profile.find({
    filter: {
        where: {
            type: 'expert',
            is_verified: 1,
            expert_category: $scope.expertCategory,
            loc: {
                'near': [lat, lng]
            }
        }
    }
}).$promise.then(function(users) {
    console.log(users);
    $scope.users = users;
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Looks like problem is something else, have you tried removing `loc: { 'near': [lat, lng]}`? Ensure it's working without lat/long param.

Comment: Try `{where: {geo: {near: {lat: 42.266271, lng: -72.6700016} }}}` - use JS object instead array.

Comment: I tried, same problem. I found that loopback only support geoquery over 2dsphere (I indexed in 2d) now a new error is showing, given above.

Comment: Hey @jaym , Changed the location field type from geopint to object solved the problem for now thanks man.

Comment: If you solved your own question, please provide an answer and mark it as accepted. (You'll get a badge if that can motivate you further)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that loopback only support geoquery over 2dsphere (I indexed in 2d) from the following link:
[Loopback: near filter on object sub-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508291/loopback-near-filter-on-object-sub-field)

Now after indexing in 2dsphere and also changed the location field type to object, problem is solved.